# Firebase transaction fails; simulator set runs just fine

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So i have been scratching my head for 2 days now with this issue.
I have the following setup for levels in the database:

```
"PublishedLevels": {
    "$levelid": {
        "private": {
          ..list of vars
        },
        "public": {
          playCount: 0,
        }

    },
}
```

Now I'm trying to execute a transaction on the playCount, but i keep getting a 'permission_denied'. However when i run it in the simulator via a set it works just fine.

I'm using the following code for the transaction:

```
var playCountRef = firebase.database().ref(`/PublishedLevels/${levelData.uid}/public/playCount`);
playCountRef.transaction(count => {
    console.log(count);
    if (count === null) {
        return count = 0;
    } else {
        return count+1;
    }
});
```

The rules set for *PublishedLevels* are:

```
"PublishedLevels": {
    ".indexOn": "private/creationDate",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": true,
  }
```

Looking forward to a nudge in the right direction!

Thanks in advance,

Erik

***update1 post now includes all rules**

***update2 even removing all the validation rules from PublishedLevels i still have the following issue:**
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full rules, not just the read/write parts.  For all we know, they could actually be in the wrong spot.  Also verify that `levelData.uid` contains exactly what you expect.

Comment: hi @DougStevenson, i just edited my post. I'm certain the levelData.uid is correct. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @DougStevenson do you have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, apparently I messed up my auto login flow. The moment this transaction is done the user is not yet logged in. I was so convinced this could not be it so I ignored that part.